# Poor performance suddenly on PostgreSQL select * from table

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-performance

I have a table that isn't overly large (139783 records). Performance was historically never an issue for this table however almost overnight, performance became extremely poor for any query that doesn't specifically have an index in the `where` clause.

This includes doing a basic `select * from example.my_table` which now takes around 8 seconds.

As far as I can tell, nothing changed schema wise when the tables performance degraded, it seemed to happen on its own which lead me to think it could be an issue with some sort of postgres internal.

I've forced a vacuum on the table and have had no improvement.

I've tried dumping all of the records from this table into a brand new one and the new one has the normal performance that we had before it degraded (running `select * from example.my_table_duplicate` takes less than 1 sec).

Ultimately, if it comes to it, I can just put the data into a new table and then rename them but I'd like to understand what could have caused this performance issue.

We are using PostgreSQL version 9.6.15, hosted on AWS RDS.

Comment: Did you run vacuum or vacuum full?  Are there any transactions that have been left idle in transaction for a long time?

Comment: If not already done, you can try to configure auto_explain that can give some clues. Do you have EXPLAIN ANALYZE output before and after the issue ? If yes, please post them.